# Jquery mobile (ListView) trigger create slow when tried to insert large number of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have found this problem and solutions in other pages but I still cannot get a perfect one.

I am looping through an array of 200 objects.

```
var stringBuffer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array; i++) {
    stringBuffer.push('<input type="radio" class="select_options" data-iconpos="right" onClick ="callClosePopup(event);" name="items" id="radio_' + array[i].ConditionId + '" ' + checked + 'value="' +  array[i].ConditionId+'_' + array[i].Description + '"/><label data-corners="false"  data-iconshadow="false" style="border-bottom:1px solid rgb(0,0,0)" for="radio_' + array[i].ConditionId + '">' + array[i].Description + '</label>');    
}
var combinedHtml = stringBuffer.join("")
$("#myListView").html(combinedHtml).trigger("create"); <=== This line consumes a lot of time (around 9 seconds on my Moto G).
```

Any Ideas to improve this?

PS: I am using jQuerymobile v-1.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried implementing this, but it may be a rough solution. I'm looking for something more elegant for my project.

This was provided by [zupkoo](https://forum.jquery.com/user/zupkoo)

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/listview-trigger-create-performance-issue-jqm-enhancement#14737000003990247

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
var s = "";
var OF;
OF = $("#test");
OF.append(s);
OF.trigger("create");
for(var i =0;i<350;i++){
    s+="<form>";
    s+="<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox-"+i+"\" />";
    s+="<label for=\"checkbox-"+i+"\">"+i+"</label>";
    s+="</form>";
}
var srcLength = 1000;
var srcNumb = 1000;
var startSrc = 0;
var ss ="";
var inter=self.setInterval(function(){
    if(s.length <= (startSrc+srcLength)){
        ss=s.substr(startSrc);
        OF.append(ss);
        OF.trigger("create");
        clearInterval(inter);$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    }else{
        ss = s.substr((startSrc),srcLength);
        var index = ss.indexOf("</form>",(srcLength-200));
        srcNumb=index+7;//</form> = 7
        startSrc+=srcNumb;
        OF.append(ss.substr(0,srcNumb));
        OF.trigger("create");
    }
},0);
```

Comment: The final solution for me, and this sped up my app a lot, was to eliminate the use of so many elements. It was on $<element selector>.create() that jQuery spent so much time producing it's modifications and handlers.